# Negate a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, negate

Im writing a simple folder watcher program, I would like to ignore a temp.temp file that gets copied into the folder when a scan is made, so the program will detect anything placed in the folder and ignore the temp.temp file. At the moment I have got the program detecting IMG files to get around the problem.

```
if(e.FullPath.Contains("IMG"))            
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("You have a Collection Form: " + e.Name);
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", e.FullPath);
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason `if(e.FullPath.Contains("temp.temp"))` wouldn't be an appropriate test, here?

Comment: What do you mean by "negate" a string? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: What exactly does *negate* mean here??

Comment: I think he means he wants to ignore that particular file. His current solution seems valid to me.

Comment: I need to ignore temp.temp and detect any file that is placed in the folder.

Comment: Well you want to ignore a temp.temp file and surprising you have the name, whatz stopping you to check the same in `FullPath` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try : `If(!e.FullPath.EndsWith("temp.temp"))`

Comment: That'll also catch `babytemp.temp`, which as I understand, should not be ignored.

Comment: Yeah ure right it should be changed to equality check if its exact file name that should be ignored

Answer (score 7):

If `e` is of type `FileInfo`, then you can use

```
if(e.FullPath.Contains("IMG") && e.Name.Equals("temp.temp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("You have a Collection Form: " + e.Name);
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", e.FullPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if by 'negate' you mean 'ignore', this should work:

```
if(Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath) != "temp.temp")            
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("You have a Collection Form: " + e.Name);
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", e.FullPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just ignore "temp.temp" how about an early return?

```
if (e.Name.Equals("temp.temp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a FileSystemWatcher use the constructor described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b30akzf.aspx to filter for files you want rather than  negate the ones you don't.